# Choice form from database SYMFONY 2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm starting with symfony 2 and i want display a "choice" type with data from database but I have a problem :

addAction :

```
    public function addAction()
{
    $categories = new CategoriesAnnonce();
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new AddFormType($categories),$categories);
    return $this->render('AnnoncesBundle::add.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

AddFormType.php :

```
    <?php

namespace AnnoncesBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class AddFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $cat;

    public function __construct(CategoriesAnnonce $categories)
    {
        $this->cat = $categories->getNomSousCategorie();
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('titre', 'text')
            ->add('categories', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $this->cat,
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AnnoncesBundle\Form\Model\Add',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Add';
    }
}

?>
```

Error :

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AnnoncesBundle\Form\Type\AddFormType::__construct() must be an instance of AnnoncesBundle\Form\Type\CategoriesAnnonce, instance of AnnoncesBundle\Entity\CategoriesAnnonce given, called in /Users/jordan/Desktop/www/Lesbonnesaffaires/src/AnnoncesBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php on line 69 and defined
```

Answer (score 2):

Its using the namespace defined in the file instead of the proper namespace to which `CategoriesAnnonce` belongs. Add a `use` statement:

`use AnnoncesBundle\Entity\CategoriesAnnonce`

OR change your type hint to the FQCN like:

```
public function __construct(\AnnoncesBundle\Entity\CategoriesAnnonce, $categories) {
  //...
}
```

> Thank's but i have a other problem now:
>
> > The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class AnnoncesBundle\Form\Model\Add, but is an instance of class AnnoncesBundle\Entity\CategoriesAnnonce. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class AnnoncesBundle\Entity\CategoriesAnnonce to an instance of AnnoncesBundle\Form\Model\Add.

This happens because you have the data_class set to `AnnoncesBundle\Form\Model\Add`:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AnnoncesBundle\Form\Model\Add',
    ));
}
```

But you are trying to pass it `AnnoncesBundle\Entity\CategoriesAnnonce`

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('titre', 'text')
        // this cat is an instance of AnnoncesBundle\Entity\CategoriesAnnonce
        ->add('categories', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => $this->cat,
    ));
}
```

I think you need to rework your code for all of this. Unfortunately i cant give specifics because I don't know what `AnnoncesBundle\Form\Model\Add` and `AnnoncesBundle\Entity\CategoriesAnnonce` and how they relate or are supposed to interact. But i suspect that you are confused about creating a [***form class***](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes) and creating a custom [***field type***](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) and possibly how you are creating your class hierarchy and what the different components should be doing. I would review the [forms chapter of the book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) and the [custom field type cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html). Then if you have issue create a new question about the specifics with the relevant code from your Entity/Model, Form, and FieldType classes.

Comment: Thank's but i have a other problem now :
The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class AnnoncesBundle\Form\Model\Add, but is an instance of class AnnoncesBundle\Entity\CategoriesAnnonce. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class AnnoncesBundle\Entity\CategoriesAnnonce to an instance of AnnoncesBundle\Form\Model\Add.

Comment: @JordanLechevin Updated my answer a bit, but Im not sure how much it will actually help you. I think your question(s) are really less about the specific errors you're getting and more about being confused about how the forms component works and interacts with Doctrine in sf2.